# "Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers" error even after using computed var for prop

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, parent-child, vuex

With the following component, I am getting an `Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.` error:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="items"
      :search="search"
      :key="tableKey"
      :pagination.sync="pagination"
      disable-initial-sort
      rowKey
    >
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
      <tr @click="clicked(props.item)" :class="{'secondary': props.item[rowKey]===selectedCode}">
        <td v-for="header in headers" :key="header.value">
          <BaseTableColumn
            :item="props.item"
            :index="header.value"
            :format="header.format"
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'BaseTable',
  props: {
    headers: Array,
    items: Array,
    search: String,
    tableKey: String,
    rowKey: String,
  },
  data: () => ({
    pagination: {
      rowsPerPage: 10,
      totalItems: -1,
    },
    selectedCode: -1,
  }),
  components: {
    BaseTableColumn: () => import('@/components/base/BaseTableColumn'),
  },
  methods: {
    clicked(row) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      this.selectedCode = row[this.rowKey];
      this.$set(row, 'selected', true);
      this.$emit('rowClick', row);
    },
    highlightFirst(items) {
      this.selectedCode = this.items[0][this.rowKey];
      this.$set(this.items[0], 'selected', true);
    },
  },
  updated() {
    if (this.selectedCode === -1 && (typeof this.items === 'object') && this.items.length > 0) {
      this.highlightFirst(this.items);
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

For reference, here is `headers.js`:

```
const headers = [
  {
    text: 'Tenant Code',
    value: 'code',
  },
  {
    text: 'Tenant ID',
    value: 'name',
  },
];

export default headers;
```

and `BaseTableColumn.vue`:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'BaseTableColumn',
  props: {
    format: Function,
    item: Object,
    index: String,
  },
  methods: {
    getText() {
      return this.item[this.index];
    },
  },
  render(createElement) {
    if (this.$props.format) {
      return this.$props.format(this.item, this.index, createElement);
    }
    return createElement('div', this.getText());
  },
};
</script>
```

The issue happens here:

```
  this.$set(this.items[0], 'selected', true);
```

However, if I follow the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow) like so:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="tableRows"
      :search="search"
      :key="tableKey"
      :pagination.sync="pagination"
      disable-initial-sort
      rowKey
    >
...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'BaseTable',
  props: {
    headers: Array,
    items: Array,
    search: String,
    tableKey: String,
    rowKey: String,
  },
...
  computed: {
    tableRows() {
      const rows = [...this.items];
      return rows;
    },
  },
...
  methods: {
...
    highlightFirst(items) {
      this.selectedCode = this.items[0][this.rowKey];
      this.$set(this.tableRows[0], 'selected', true);
    },
  },
  updated() {
    if (this.selectedCode === -1 && (typeof this.tableRows === 'object') && this.tableRows.length > 0) {
      this.highlightFirst(this.tableRows);
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

I still get the errors, specifically in the `updated()` hook and the `highlightFirst()` method, even though I'm not referencing or mutating a prop. What else do I need to change to get rid of this error?

Comment: Do you have a global store attached to the root of the app? Like in main.js or such? The problem is that you're changing that store's state directly, which isn't allowed. - https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/

Comment: The error message doesn't say that you're mutating a prop: that's a different error message. This error is about mutating data held in the store. From a one-way data flow perspective the store is treated like an independent root node, so any data held in the store can only be changed via store mutations. While it isn't shown in the code we can deduce that `items`, or at least the objects in it, are also held in store state. Difficult to know what to advise without knowing what the `selected` property is used for.

Comment: @Jesper Yes, I am using Vuex store. However, I thought that using the computed value with the spread operator - `const rows = [...this.items];` - would break that link and put it in an independent variable. I take it that's not the case? The code works fine; I just get console errors.

Comment: You can only break the link if you directly copy the Array / Object, this can be done for Objects with `Object.assign({}, this.items)`, and for Arrays you can `this.items.splice(0, 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I eventually solved this problem was to emit an event and use the `row` value in the parent component:

```
clicked(row) {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  this.selectedCode = row[this.rowKey];
  this.$emit('rowClick', row);
},
```

However, to @Jesper's point above, since then, I have been using `Object.assign()` in cases like this where I need to break the link to Vuex.